# Smoother Transition between application in windows app, c#

Tags: c#

My application handles the startup and termination of external some application.
An inbuilt TaskBar is there to tab the applications that are started.

Say when three applications are started, i map those 3 applications to the tabs created. So that the user can use the task bar to switch between the application. The default windows task bar will be replaced by my applications taskbar because it is a Kiosk application.

All these works fine...

What i want to do is, the toggling between the applications is not smooth, which the user dosent like.
I want to make the change of applications smooth. I am using windows XP.

I am calling ShowWindowsAsync function to show the application when user clicks the respective tab.

How can i make the the visual effective using c# ? Is there any possibility ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it is not smooth? What platform/language are you using?

Comment: To be more clear i want Like fade in and fade out using c# win xp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P/Invoke AnimateWindow() to get transitions.  Visit pinvoke.net for the required declarations.

Comment: I am already using SetWindowsPos() to show the forms. How can i use Animatewindows(). Thanks.